# How to check if object is not None within a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am somehow familiar with list comprehensions in Python. But in situations when I need to check if the list is not None, the list comprehension would fail.

e.g.

```
tags = v.tags
if tags:
    for t in tags:
        if t['Key'] == 'Name':
            # Do something
```

Now, if tags is None, then the following list comprehension fails. It works fine if tags is empty/[]. I would like a list comprehension that checks against None.

```
[k for k,v in tags if tags]:
```

Comment: you are trying to loop over `tags`.. You can do this with empty collectors (`[]`, `()`, `{}`) but not over `None`.

Comment: Why do you need a list comprehension.

Comment: Shortest way: `[k for k,v in (tags or [])]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about this:

```
[k for k in (tags or [])]
```

Let's see what happens for both cases:

- `>>> tags = None`

  ```
  >>> [k for k in (tags or [])]
  []
  ```
- `tags = [1, 2, 3]`

  ```
  >>> [k for k in (tags or [])]
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```

---

The reason this works is because `(tags or [])` returns `tags` only if `bool(tags) == True`. Otherwise it returns the second argument, in this case `[]`, even if its boolean value is also `False`. That way, we either loop over `tags`, if it exists` or over an empty list if it doesn't.

Comment: Brilliant! A clean solution that avoids an if statement to check if the object is not None.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a ternary condition here:

```
([k for k, v in tags] if tags is not None else [])
```

You can embed the ternary condition in the comprehension as well:

```
[k for k, v in (tags if tags is not None else [])]
```

---

As a side note, `[k for k, v in tags if tags]` does not really behave as you might expect.
The `if` clause of a list comprehension is evaluated at each iteration, meaning that the truth value of `tags` is checked for each element in it.

To prove this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def is_empty(l):
    print("is_empty")
    return len(l) > 0

m = [i for i in l if is_empty(l)]

print(m)
```

Output:

```
is_empty
is_empty
is_empty
is_empty
is_empty
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What you are semantically looking for is an inline `if`, that is, in Python, a ternary condition.

Answer (score 5):

You can test with a preceding if block

```
if tags is not None:
   ...
```

Or *short-circuit* with an empty iterable:

```
>>> tags = None
>>> [k for k, _ in tags or ()]
[]
```