# Pythonic way to check if number is not None and do something

Tags: python, dictionary

It seems pretty basic to me, but I didn't found a good solution.

Assuming a dictionary like:

```
data = {'values' : [1.3333, None, 2.44444], 'other_values' : [2.3333, 1.2222, None]}
```

Because the built-in function `round()` obviously can't round `None`'s, this returns an error:

```
for index in range(0, len(data['values'])):
    result = round(data['values'][index], 2)
    print(result)
    result2 = round(data['other_values'][index], 2)
    print(result2)
```

A possible solution is something like this

```
for index in range(0, len(data['values'])):
    if data['values'][index]:
        result = round(data['values'][index], 2)
        print(result)
    if data['other_values'][index]:
        result2 = round(data['other_values'][index], 2)
        print(result2)
```

but is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if object is not None within a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807107/how-to-check-if-object-is-not-none-within-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: In some cases it is better to use `math.nan` rather than `None` to represent invalid values. The former can undergo many mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you expect from the output. When you have the given `values` and `other_values` as keys, and just want to simply print out the round numbers, and ignoring `None`, maybe you can try this:

```
print([round(i, 2) for i in data['values'] if i is not None]) # so you still have 0 if there was any 0 in the data
print([round(i, 2) for i in data['other_values'] if i is not None])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `round(x, 2)` you could do `round(x or 0, 2)`.

Comment: This is clever but changes the result. Instead of `None` being preserved, you get 0. Also, it doesn't really help with OP's unpythonic `range` loop and `if` statements.

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah, but even their own "possible solution" changes the result (in a different way - zeros aren't printed anymore), so I figured this might work as well. Can't tell if they don't say what exactly they want and only show two disagreeing codes.

Comment: Good point, I missed that they're not even mutating their structure. I guess the question is unclear since all they're doing is printing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
data = {'values' : [1.3333, None, 2.44444], 'other_values' : [2.3333, 1.2222, None]}
lst = []
for key in data:
    lst.extend([round(num,2) for num in data[key] if num])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[1.33, 2.44, 2.33, 1.22]
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance` attribute

Like: if `data['values'][0]` is an attribute of float, then print

```
if isinstance(data['values'][index], float):
```

Full code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'values': [1.3333, None, 2.44444],
            'other_values': [2.3333, 1.2222, None]}

    for index in range(0, len(data['values'])):
        if isinstance(data['values'][index], float):
            result = round(data['values'][index], 2)
            print(result)
        if isinstance(data['other_values'][index], float):
            result2 = round(data['other_values'][index], 2)
            print(result2)
```

Output:

```
1.33
2.33
1.22
2.44
```